# How use Eigen library in Dev C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, installation, eigen

I downloaded the library from eigen.tuxfamily and decompress in a folder called eigen. My code in Dev C++ is (and he is in the same directory of eigen folder):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen/Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

MatrixXd m(2,2);

int main()
{
       m(0,0) = 3;
       m(1,0) = 2.5;
       m(0,1) = -1;
       m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
       cout << m << endl;
}
```

But the program displays the following error:

eigen/Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory. 
And more errors arising.

Have I to set something in the program? How to fix it?
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

It look to me as a bad idea to work inside eigen's directory. The quick fix is to replace `<>` by `"` in

```
#include <eigen/Eigen/Dense>
```

To get

```
#include "eigen/Eigen/Dense"
```

However you should consider using gcc `-I` `-L` `-l` flags to use an external library.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the path to the include and library directories for your library.

I have Dev cpp 4.9.9.2:

1. In the main window of Dev-cpp click on Project -> Project options -> Directories.
2. library directories tab: Here you have an icon to browse for a folder that should include some .lib or .a file
3. Include directories: add a directory here that contains .h files
4. Switch to parameters tab, because you have to choose a library file that will be linked with your program... click on add library or object and find the .a file.
5. experiment with adding or removing directory names from your #include-s.